# GeoPackage with Dbeaver

Tags: sqlite, qgis, dbeaver, spatialite, geopackage

How can i use GeoPackage in Dbeaver? I mean spatial functions for geometry.

If i use Sqlite-connections in Dbeaver, i cant use spatial functions like st_intersections(geom,geom) and others.

For example, if i use PostgreSQL in DBeaver -- it does not problem, i have full support for Posrgis functions.

I try to find new driver for DBeaver, maybe for Spatialite, but i cant.

May be anybody find someways how to use GeoPackage in DBeaver correctly ?

THANK YOU!